# Wordpress url shows page not found on localhost, but online its fine

Tags: wordpress, httpd.conf, hosts-file

I have installed wordpress, now the http://localhost/wp-login.php and the likes are okay.  Assuming that I want to go to a page such such as http://localhost/something-here/ gives me a 404 error.  This 404 error happens only on localhost not on a live server.

What is the reason for this.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled on the local server?

Comment: hmm assuming no, since I am short of time, how do I get i enable it, I am using a wamp

Comment: mod_rewrite.so is enabled in httpd.conf

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: I altered the permalinks to ?id=14

Answer (score 2):

Try flushing your URLs: go to *Settings* → *Permalinks* → *Update*.

Comment: The flushing will not work, its some settings in the php.ini or the httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

In **WAMP** what you can do is go to `WAMP icon in the system tray > Apache > Apache Modules > Tick the rewrite_module`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp, click on the wamp icon and: `Apache > Apache Modules >` ensure rewrite_module is ticked.

Comment: rewrite_module is uncommented

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps 
1. URLs: go to Settings → Permalinks Setting→ Common Settings
2. select the default url format for local server